# rosserial: Permission denied

Tags: ros, serial, ros-kinetic, permission, rosserial

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hello,

I had to re-install my Ubuntu 16.04 with kinetic for some reasons. How ever, I tried to re-install all the work I've done before on the project.
All the workspaces where saved in my onwcloud, so i thought it should be an easy thing to do. Wrong :)

As I tried just to recompile the workspace with catkin_make everything failed an i tried to build from a new and clean workspace.
There is a node that uses some serial communication,so i need to add the rosserial pkg to my system.
First try by `sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-serial`. then I did `catkin_make`. Everything fine so far. BUT when i start the node with `rosrun` an exeption ocoured:

```
IO Exception (13): Permission denied, file /tmp/binarydeb/ros-kinetic-serial-1.2.1/src/impl/unix.cc, line 151.
```

Just to check, i manually install the serial-pkg in my workspace and build both mith catkin. Now ther ist that error:

```
IO Exception (13): Permission denied, file /home/eddie/owncloud/eddie_ws/src/serial/src/impl/unix.cc, line 151.
```

which is basicly the same.

The piece of code with this revers to ist that: (l.151 is the default case)

```
void
Serial::SerialImpl::open ()
{
  if (port_.empty ()) {
    throw invalid_argument ("Empty port is invalid.");
  }
  if (is_open_ == true) {
    throw SerialException ("Serial port already open.");
  }

  fd_ = ::open (port_.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK);

  if (fd_ == -1) {
    switch (errno) {
    case EINTR:
      // Recurse because this is a recoverable error.
      open ();
      return;
    case ENFILE:
    case EMFILE:
      THROW (IOException, "Too many file handles open.");
    default:
      THROW (IOException, errno);
    }
  }

  reconfigurePort();
  is_open_ = true;
}
```

Does anyone has any ideas?
thank you all!
p.s. the hole thing worked very good before the re installation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303073/rosserial:-permission-denied/) by [lorenznew](https://answers.ros.org/users/36568/lorenznew/) on ROS Answers with karma: 123 on 2018-09-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You most likely had a `udev` file that set the correct permissions on your serial port so your user had read/write access.

*Or* on your old installation your user account was a member of the `dialout` group. See #q189457 for what is probably a related question.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2018-09-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lorenznew](https://answers.ros.org/users/36568/lorenznew/) on 2018-09-12**:
WOW! nice! Thank you! I found the solution thanks to your comment!
Just need to do: `sudo adduser <second_user> dialout` and restart the PC.
Thanks!!